# Get a list of private YouTube videos of a user's account with help of API

Tags: php, oauth, youtube-api

We're going to use our business' Youtube account to store private videos that our users upload (sports related). So we're going to set the videos private in the Youtube account as soon as they're uploaded.

We want to then use the API to retrieve a list of videos. When a user wants to watch one through our interface, we'll briefly mark it public until it starts playing and then change it back to private.

My question is: Is it possible to retrieve a list of videos in our YouTube account without having to go through the Oauth steps? I.e. We just want to display the private videos from our business' account using the API. Our Google API account is the same Google account as we use for Youtube.

A PHP example would be awesome!!

All of the examples I've seen are for a user logging in to their own Youtube account to get the Oauth token and then listing videos from their account.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see the problem in logging in to your business' YouTube account exactly?

Comment: Our customers need to be able to see a list of private videos from our  Youtube account when they're in a certain section of our interface. They don't have access to our account obviously.

Comment: Of course not, but why can't your API login to your YT account on the backend, which obviously is inaccessible to the client?

Comment: How do I do that? I have searched endlessly but don't see any way to login using the API key- it always ends up going back to wanting an Oauth 2 authentication process...

Comment: @Henry Weber: I have your same exact problem (with v3 API)... I couldn't **server side** authenticate with OAuth either... :-( Did you finally solve this issue? Anybody else: any clues?

Comment: @MarcoS No, we ended up going with another solution.. Wistia.